# "Зелёная экономика"

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Почему словосочетание "зелёная экономика" взято в кавычки?

Comment: Контекст дайте. В принципе-то можно согласиться, что выражение пока не стало общепринятым, поэтому кавычки вполне мотивированы. Но надо смотреть контекст, возможно, что в определенных текстах они излишни. Ну и есть еще вариант, что автор подразумевает под этим нечто особое.

Answer (score 1):

**Зелëная экономика** — направление в экономической науке, сформировавшееся в последние два десятилетия, в рамках которого считается, что экономика является зависимым компонентом **природной среды,** в пределах которой она существует и является её частью. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зелёная_экономика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

**В специальной литературе** сочетание ***зеленая экономика*** пишется без кавычек, но в популярных журнальных статьях используются кавычки, так как термин имеет **условное название**, которое пока еще не является общеизвестным (англ. **Green economics, Ecological economics**).

Можно встретить два варианта:

(1) «Зеленая» экономика – особая модель экономики.

(2) «Зеленая экономика» – это экономика завтрашнего дня, и именно она должна стать движущей силой экономического развития XXI столетия.

Более корректным, как мне кажется, является написание "зеленая экономика", то есть всё сочетание имеет условное значение.

Comment: без контекста все это - гадание на кофейной гуще. А вдруг автор обозвал так экономику Украины после прихода Зеленского? !))) Или еще что этакое. Отсюда и кавычки.

Answer (score 0):

Постараюсь объяснить наиболее понятно. Полагаю, вопрос возник из-за того, что сочетание было заключено в кавычки целиком. Приведу примеры:

**С дуба падали "зелёные" (в действительности они были больше тёмными и сильно испачканными) листья.**
Здесь слово *зелёные* употреблено в переносном смысле, т. к. листья таковыми не являлись. Также данное слово может быть употреблено в различных смыслах, зависящих от текущей ситуации. В общем,  переносное значение касается **исключительно прилагательного**.

**Сегодня было "зелёное затмение".**

Здесь "зелёное" не является самостоятельным термином, а относится к слову "затмение", образуя с ним **единое сочетание**, имеющее свой, **уникальный** смысл. Надеюсь, логика понятна.

Таким образом, термин "зелёная экономика" подразумевает некоторое понятие, не соответствующее смыслу, доносимому прилагательным с существительным , поэтому заключается в кавычки.

**UPD**: термин "зелёное затмение" — плод моего воображения.

Comment: *>> Постараюсь объяснить наиболее понятно* Получилось наоборот. С дуба падали "зелёные" листья - вы такое где-нибудь видели? Вот чтоб в кавычках? И какой же тут переносный смысл? Молодые, несмышлёные?